# SensorEventListener in separate thread

Tags: android, events

This seems like a basic question, but after searching for a while and playing with it, I've come to the point where some help would be appreciated.  I would like to have a SensorEventListener run in a separate thread from the UI, so that computations that need to occur when events come in won't slow down the UI.

My latest attempt looks like:

```
class SensorThread extends Thread {
    SensorManager mSensorManager;
    Sensor mSensor;

    public void run() {
        Log.d( "RunTag", Thread.currentThread().getName() ); // To display thread
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService( SENSOR_SERVICE  );
        mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor( Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER );
        MySensorListener msl = new MySensorListener();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(msl, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI );
    }

    private class MySensorListener implements SensorEventListener {
        public void onAccuracyChanged (Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            Log.d( "ListenerTag", Thread.currentThread().getName() ); // To display thread
        }
    }
```

In the activity's (or service's) onCreate(), I create a SensorThread object and call its start() method.  As you would expect, the debug log shows the "RunTag" entry in the new thread.  But onSensorChanged()'s "ListenerTag" is running in the main thread, even though its object is instantiated in the new thread.  How do I change that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Acclerometer Sensor in Separate Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513352/acclerometer-sensor-in-separate-thread)

Answer (score 23):

A little late, but if others still want to know, here is a good way to achieve this. As always when multithreading, make sure you know what you are doing and take the time to so it right, to avoid those weird errors. Have fun!

Class members:

```
private HandlerThread mSensorThread;
private Handler mSensorHandler;
```

in OnCreate or when registering:

```
mSensorThread = new HandlerThread("Sensor thread", Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
mSensorThread.start();
mSensorHandler = new Handler(mSensorThread.getLooper()) //Blocks until looper is prepared, which is fairly quick
yourSensorManager.registerListener(yourListener, yourSensor, interval, mSensorHandler);
```

When unregistering, also do:

```
mSensorThread.quitSafely();
```

Comment: perhaps the best answer

Comment: `Thread.MAX_PRIORITY` should be changed to `Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE` as recommended in [HandlerThread Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html#HandlerThread(java.lang.String,%20int))

"[...] The value supplied must be from Process and not from java.lang.Thread."

Comment: Can you use the same mSensorThread/mSensorHandler for different sensors? Or you should better have per each sensor new ones?

Answer (score 13):

You can receive sensor event in a background thread. Instead of

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(msl, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI );
```

you can declare it with a handler referring to a secondary thread. The run loop of a thread looks like this:

```
...
run {
    Looper.prepare;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    ...
    mSensorManager.registerListener(msl, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI, handler );
    Looper.loop();
}
...
```

Comment: public void run(){... and Looper.prepare();

Comment: Or use android.os.HandlerThread and create a Handler: new Handler(yourHandlerThread.getLooper())

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the SensorManager is actually responsible for calling the onSensorChanged method, and I don't think the fact that registerListener is called in this separate thread is going to make any difference. The easiest thing to do is probably to make onSensorChanged return instantly, by delegating all the heavy lifting to a separate thread. Or perhaps to an ASyncTask, which seems to be the official "right way" of doing such things.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I come from the 8-bit micro world, so I may need to adjust my thinking some.  Allocating new tasks every time the sensor changes (5-50x a second, depending on sample rate) seems like a waste.

Comment: Well, maybe it would only allocate the task in certain cases. For example, maybe it stores the sensor reading in memory, and then checks in the onSensorChanged method whether the reading has changed more than some threshold. If it has, THEN it starts up the ASyncTask. I'm really just getting started with Android though, so I don't really know what will work best.

Comment: OnSensorChanged should really run in ASyncTask - even if your main class is a background service(like in my case) it may be that if don't return fast enough from the method, the next call of SensorManager cannot be made...

Answer (score 1):

Get the handler of the thread and register the listener on that thread. For example:

```
public void run() {
    Sensor sensor = this.sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
    Looper.prepare();
    Handler gHandler = new Handler();
    this.sensorManager.registerListener(gravitySensorEventListener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, gHandler);
    Looper.loop();
}
```

hopes this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create handler for the current thread where you are registering your listener and pass it to the listener as third argument.

```
public void run() {
    Log.d( "RunTag", Thread.currentThread().getName() ); // To display thread
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService( SENSOR_SERVICE  );
    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor( Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER );
    MySensorListener msl = new MySensorListener();
    Looper.perpare;
    Handler hndlr = new Handler();

    mSensorManager.registerListener(msl, mSensor, 
     SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI, hndlr);
    Looper.loop;

    }
```