# android: getting movement sensor in a service

Tags: android, service, sensors

I need to get the movement (send by sensor) in a Service where I use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor()` to start frequently some methods.

to be clearer I need to get in the background the movement of the device.

The problem is that from this method one need to register MovementListener, and it seems not  possible to do that because this method itself is launched in a Service and the service can't have a `looper` and so can't receive message?

Do you have a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6759844/1025599