# Are java and/or android events concurrent?

Tags: java, android, concurrency

I'm trying to make an android app using some of the mobile's sensors. I was thinking some like this.

```
public class ListenerSensores implements SensorEventListener {

   LinkedBlockingQueue<float[]> acelerations = new LinkedBlockingQueue();

    public void onSensorChanged (SensorEvent event) {
        //Add event values to the data structure
    }

  private ArrayList<float[]> obtainLastXValues(LinkedBlockingQueue<float[]> queue, int amount) {

    ArrayList<float[]> values = new ArrayList<float[]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; ++i) {
      while(queue.isEmpty()){
        //wait
      }

      float data[] = new float[4];
      data = queue.poll();
      float thing[] = {data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]};
      values.add(thing);
    }

    return values;
  }
```

Should I use something LinkedBlockingQueue or something simpler like LinkedList would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Are Java and/or Android events concurrent?

The answer is - it depends on how the specific API was designed, not on Java and/or Android. So in each case you need to read the doc find out on which thread it's called. But in most of the cases it would be just a main thread, because it's more convenient and scalable later. If you need, you can process any callback in your own thread.

2) SensorEventListener by default runs on UI thread. But you can pass a Handler to move processing to some of your threads with Looper.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [SensorEventListener in separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286815/sensoreventlistener-in-separate-thread) the default is that it is run on UI thread but you can change it by using handler as last parameter of SensorManager.registerListener().