# (Android) How to get sensor value from separated thread?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make android application that get sensor value from separated thread.
While wandering without finding a solution, I found the following good question([SensorEventListener in separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286815/sensoreventlistener-in-separate-thread)).
I applied this to my code, but this application terminates immediately every time I run it.
Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ActivityMainBinding binding;

SensorManager sensorManager;
Sensor sensor;

private HandlerThread mSensorThread;
private Handler mSensorHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    setContentView(view);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);

    final SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        Message message = mSensorHandler.obtainMessage();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY) {
                bundle.putFloat("value", event.values[2]); // get Z-axis value
                message.setData(bundle);
                mSensorHandler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }
    };

    mSensorThread = new HandlerThread("Sensor thread", Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    mSensorThread.start();
    mSensorHandler = new Handler(mSensorThread.getLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
            float value = bundle.getFloat("value");
            binding.textView.setText(Float.toString(value)); // print sensor value on textView
        }
    };
    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI, mSensorHandler);
}
```

The code looks very strange to me, too. But I wandered for a few days and couldn't find a solution. How can I change this code?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have other reasons to create a separate thread, it will be a lot easier if you do everything in the same thread. You should see the reason you application terminates if you look at logcat. In this case, it is because you are calling binding.textView.setText from the background thread. You can only update the UI from the main thread. Doing everything in the same thread eliminates this situation. If you really need the second thread, you will need to send an intent (with the sensor value stored as an extra) from the background thread to the main thread. The main thread will have a BroadcastReceiver to receive the intent, get the extra, then update binding.textView.setText.