# Multithreading sensors

Tags: android, multithreading, sensors

How do you make it soo each sensor runs in a different thread, I have 4 sensors and I want one thread to deal with each one of them.

I have tried to create the thread when registering:

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                sensorManager.registerListener(MainActivity.this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            }
        }).start();
```

And I have also tried to create the thread on the onSensorChange function, I write the value from the sensors into files

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34808131/17856705) seems to do just what you need - notice the use of the `registerListener` with a 4th parameter for the specified handler created using a separate thread's looper.

Comment: Soo the onSensorChange function would still be the same and just by registering the sensor on a seperate thread the function would also be executed in that seperate thread?

Comment: That's correct - but as the answer alludes to when operating under a separate thread the focus is then on what you are planning on doing in the listener method.  You may want to include your listener code so someone can review that for any potential issues.

Comment: Note: `registerListener(...)` returns _immediately._ There is no reason to create a new thread in which to call it. Even if you follow @Gardener's advice and use the four or five arg version, there's still no reason to create a new thread in which to call `registerListener`. The identity of the thread that registers the listener does not affect which thread eventually will call the listener's `onSensorChanged(...)` method.

Comment: @Solomon Slow As is shown in the referenced answer, it is the listener code that is of interest which is invoked using the thread's looper which is the purpose of the handler as the 4th parameter.  Where the registerListener is done is not relevant but it is agreed that the posted code is wrong as  you noted.